# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your…

Tags: android

The pattern of this crash is kinda weird. sometimes it is okay, but after a while when I try to navigate from one activity to another it happen (for example: from MainActivity to AnotherActivity), but sometimes it doesn't crash. And sometimes it also crashes when I click next page or previous page  option, which display the next 7 or previous 7 contents from the database. Sometimes it gets even weirder that it crashes the moment I run the program. 
I already used this function:

```
@Override
public void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) { 
     imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Please, please help is needed the most F1 me please, I'm newbie???

Thank you very much!

LogCat:

```
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131361798, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.mysoft.saddis.MainActivity$ImageAdapter)]
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1545)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2012)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1660)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at android.widget.TableLayout.onLayout(TableLayout.java:448)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:349)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1976)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1730)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-20 18:34:01.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1746):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.mysoft.saddis;

//all the necessary imports are imported

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView lstView;
    private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;

    public int currentPage = 1;
    public int TotalPage = 0;

    public Button btnNext;
    public Button btnPre;

    public boolean orientation;
    boolean verOk = Splash.version;

    public static String urlPageNumHolder;

    public ProgressDialog dialog;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        // Bets orientation
        onConfigurationChanged(null);

        // ListView and imageAdapter
        lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lstView.setClipToPadding(false);
        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        lstView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

        // Next
        btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        // Perform action on click
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                currentPage = currentPage + 1;
                ShowData();
            }
        });

        // Previous
        btnPre = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPre);
        // Perform action on click
        btnPre.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                currentPage = currentPage - 1;
                ShowData();
            }
        });

        // Show first load
        ShowData();

        // OnClick
        lstView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {
                loadPage(position);

                if(verOk==true){
                    Intent subActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                            Webber.class);

                    Bundle translateBundle = ActivityOptions
                            .makeCustomAnimation(MainActivity.this,
                                    R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left)
                            .toBundle();
                    startActivity(subActivity, translateBundle);
                } else{
                    Intent subActivity = new Intent("com.mysoft.saddis.WEBBER");
                    startActivity(subActivity);
                }

            }
        });

        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");

    }

    public void ShowData() {
        btnNext.setEnabled(false);
        btnPre.setEnabled(false);

        new LoadContentFromServer().execute();

        if (orientation == false)
            dialog = ProgressDialog
                    .show(this, "ዜና", "ትንሽ ይታገሱ...", true, false);
        else
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "News", "Loading...", true,
                    false);

    }

    public void loadPage(int position) {

        // Hold Detail's URL
        urlPageNumHolder = MyArrList.get(position).get("id").toString();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        Configuration c = getResources().getConfiguration();

        if (c.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            orientation = true; // portrait

        } else if (c.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            orientation = false; // landscape

        }
    }

    class LoadContentFromServer extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Object> {

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {

            String url = "http://10.0.2.2/android/saddis/mobile/news/getNews.php";

            JSONArray data;
            try {
                data = new JSONArray(getJSONUrl(url));

                MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
                HashMap<String, Object> map;

                int displayPerPage = 7; // Per Page
                int TotalRows = data.length();
                int indexRowStart = ((displayPerPage * currentPage) - displayPerPage);

                if (TotalRows <= displayPerPage) {
                    TotalPage = 1;
                } else if ((TotalRows % displayPerPage) == 0) {
                    TotalPage = (TotalRows / displayPerPage);
                } else {
                    TotalPage = (TotalRows / displayPerPage) + 1;
                    TotalPage = (int) TotalPage;
                }
                int indexRowEnd = displayPerPage * currentPage;
                if (indexRowEnd > TotalRows) {
                    indexRowEnd = TotalRows;
                }

                String imgPath;

                for (int i = indexRowStart; i < indexRowEnd; i++) {
                    JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
                    map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    map.put("id", (String) c.getString("id"));
                    map.put("title_en", (String) c.getString("title_en"));
                    map.put("description_en", (String) c.getString("description_en"));

                    map.put("title_am", (String) c.getString("title_am"));
                    map.put("description_am", (String) c.getString("description_am"));

                    map.put("posteddate", (String) c.getString("posteddate"));

                    // Thumbnail Get ImageBitmap To Object
                    imgPath = "http://10.0.2.2/android/saddis/addis_img_gallery/news_thumb_"+c.getString("id")+".png";
                    map.put("imagepath", imgPath);
                    Bitmap newBitmap = loadBitmap(imgPath);
                    map.put("ImagePathBitmap", newBitmap);

                    MyArrList.add(map);

                    publishProgress(i);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {

            // Disabled Button Next
            if (currentPage >= TotalPage) {
                btnNext.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                btnNext.setEnabled(true);
            }

            // Disabled Button Previous
            if (currentPage <= 1) {
                btnPre.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                btnPre.setEnabled(true);
            }

            // dismiss the progress dialog
            if (dialog != null)
                dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context mContext;

        public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return MyArrList.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return MyArrList.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_column, null);
            }

            // ImagePath
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.ColImagePath);
            imageView.getLayoutParams().height = 150;
            imageView.getLayoutParams().width = 150;
            imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            try {
                imageView.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) MyArrList.get(position).get(
                        "ImagePathBitmap"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                imageView
                        .setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image);
            }

            //String qen = simpleDateFormat.format(MyArrList.get(position).get("posteddate"));

            // ID, Title, Desc and DateTime
            TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.title);
            txtTitle.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            TextView txtDesc = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.description);
            txtDesc.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            TextView txtDateTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dateTime);
            //txtDateTime.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("posteddate").toString());
            txtDateTime.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("posteddate").toString());

            if (orientation == false) {
                txtTitle.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("title_am").toString());
                txtDesc.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("description_am")
                    .toString());
            }
            else{
                txtTitle.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("title_en").toString());
                txtDesc.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("description_en")
                        .toString());
            }

            return convertView;

        }

    }

    /*** Get JSON Code from URL ***/
    public String getJSONUrl(String url) {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) { // Download OK
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    str.append(line);
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("Log", "Failed to download file..");
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return str.toString();
    }

    /***** Get Image Resource from URL (Start) *****/
    private static final String TAG = "Image";
    private static final int IO_BUFFER_SIZE = 4 * 1024;

    public static Bitmap loadBitmap(String url) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        BufferedOutputStream out = null;

        try {
            in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(url).openStream(),
                    IO_BUFFER_SIZE);

            final ByteArrayOutputStream dataStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(dataStream, IO_BUFFER_SIZE);
            copy(in, out);
            out.flush();

            final byte[] data = dataStream.toByteArray();
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            // options.inSampleSize = 1;

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length,
                    options);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not load Bitmap from: " + url);
        } finally {
            closeStream(in);
            closeStream(out);
        }

        return bitmap;
    }

    private static void closeStream(Closeable stream) {
        if (stream != null) {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                android.util.Log.e(TAG, "Could not close stream", e);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out)
            throws IOException {
        byte[] b = new byte[IO_BUFFER_SIZE];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(b)) != -1) {
            out.write(b, 0, read);
        }
    }

    /***** Get Image Resource from URL (End) *****/

    @Override
    public void finish() {
        super.finish();
        if(verOk==true){
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        // webview.saveState(outState);
        Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        // webview.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
        // lstView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState");
    }

}
```

Comment: where ever you are setting data to your listview or gridview add line adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I already have this function:
`@Override
public void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
 imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}`

Comment: But you change a datasource that your adapter uses in doInBackground with MyArrList.add(map). Doing so is not thread safe, hence this randomly occuring error. Only update data, that an adapter is using, on the UI thread followed by a call to notifydatasetchanged. The link by njzk2 above explains this in detail.

Comment: I read it, but because I'm really new for android, it was tough for me to understand, so could you edit my code please?